# how to change installation location for my app in android

Tags: android, installation

I'm creating an appstore for android applications. Whenever an app is installed from my appstore, it should be installed in /data/app/mycompanyname folder and not in any other installation location. I'm doing this for the purpose of administration and control.

So far browsing through web, I came to know that we can change it by specifying in manifest file.

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
...>`

But using that, we can specify whether we should install in internal storage or external storage. we cannot give exact path for installation using this manifest.

Can anyone help me figure out this..??
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever an app is installed from my appstore, it should be installed in /data/app/mycompanyname folder and not in any other installation location.

You do not have that degree of control. Your app will be installed at a path determined by the device manufacturer.

> But using that, we can specify whether we should install in internal storage or external storage. we cannot give exact path for installation using this manifest.

Correct.